# How can I represent a hierarchy in nested dictionary form?

Tags: python, recursion, hierarchical-data

I'm building a language model and I'd like it to recognize words that have certain properties as also having other properties that the first properties are a subset of. For example, if a word is tagged as "transport" (e.g. a train), I want my program to understand that it should also be assigned the property "container", and that, because it has the property, "container", it should also be assigned the property, "physical" because it's a physical object.

I'm thinking it should be possible to convert a simple CSV file with each row containing one edge (e.g. ['physical', 'container'] to indicate that 'container' is a child property of 'physical' and therefore all words in 'container' category should also be in 'physical' category) into a layered Python dictionary, using recursion, which can then be traversed when my program needs to find all words that possess a specific property. But I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the recursive function that could read the CSV and build the dictionary.

My hierarchy CSV looks like this:

physical edible

physical alive

alive people

physical clothing

physical container

abstract (none)

pn (none)

container transport

transport car

container crossable

My current attempt at the recursive function is this:

```
def add(cat, dct):
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == cat and row[1] != 'none':
            if row[0] not in dct:
                dct[row[0]] = {} 
            dct[row[0]][row[1]] = add(row[1], dct)
    return {}

with open('hierarchy.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as hfile:
    reader = list(csv.reader(hfile, delimiter=";"))
    hierarchy = {}
    for row in reader:
        hierarchy[row[0]] = add(row[0], hierarchy)
```

But it returns this:
{'physical': {}, 'alive': {'people': {}}, 'container': {}, 'transport': {'car': {}}, 'abstract': {}, 'pn': {}}

...which only goes two levels deep and misses a lot of the edges.

The desired output would be:

{
'physical':
{'edible':
{}
},
{'alive':
{'people':
{}
}
},
{'clothing':
{}
},
{'container':
{'transport':
{'car':
{}
}
},
{'crossable':
{}
}
},
{
'abstract':
{}
},
'pn':
{}
}
}

Any tips on how best to do this?

Comment: First, I'd recommend writing down exactly the output you expect, before trying to fix your code.

Comment: I haven't worked with graphs, but I suspect that that would be a data structure better suited to your problem. Have you checked out networkx?

Answer (score 2):

You can try it without the recursion. Create an *index* dictionary where you will check if you have seen this key before (assuming the keys in your input CSV are unique across each depth level):

```py
txt = """\
physical edible
physical alive
alive people
physical clothing
physical container
abstract (none)
pn (none)
container transport
transport car
container crossable"""

index, out = {}, {}
for c1, c2 in map(str.split, txt.splitlines()):
    if c1 not in index:
        out[c1] = index[c1] = {}
    
    if c2 != "(none)":
        index[c1][c2] = index[c2] = {}

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "physical": {
        "edible": {},
        "alive": {"people": {}},
        "clothing": {},
        "container": {"transport": {"car": {}}, "crossable": {}},
    },
    "abstract": {},
    "pn": {},
}
```

Comment: I ran it and crossable was different: `{'physical': {'edible': {}, 'alive': {'people': {}}, 'clothing': {}, 'container': {'transport': {'car': {}}, 'crossable': {}}}, 'abstract': {}, 'pn': {}}`

Comment: This isn't a criticism of your code, which is great, but I wonder if this is the right data structure for the problem.  Might many categories be subcategories of many categories that aren't totally ordered, and therefore need to be listed many times in the dictionary? And if the purpose of this data structure is to look up a category, and retrieve every category it is a subcategory of, how would you execute that query with this data structure? Is it efficient?

Comment: @Joe I don't have any experience with language models so I cannot judge the structure. From my experience I'd go rather for more flat structures in general, to process them more straightforwardly.

Comment: I'd use a directed acyclic graph, with the [ancestors](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.ancestors.html#networkx.algorithms.dag.ancestors) method (or descendants, depending on the direction). I don't know how it's implemented, but I think `networkx` is a popular package, so hopefully it is implemented efficiently.